# How can I clear map data from Folium with Python

Tags: python, folium

I am creating a map object "mymap" in folium with layers and would like to clear it completely after I'm done with it.

mymap = () and del(mymap) don't seem to work. Does anyone know if this is possible?

If it helps here is how I'm creating the map from Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import folium
from collections import defaultdict

ddfg = defaultdict()
for layer in dftemp['layers'].unique():
    ddfg[layer] = folium.FeatureGroup(name=layer)

mymap = folium.Map(location=[lat_mean, lon_mean], zoom_start=14, tiles='Stamen Toner')

for lat,lon,popup,color in zip(dftemp['lat'],dftemp['lon'],dftemp['popup'],
                                 dftemp['color']):

       ddfg[layer].add_child(folium.CircleMarker([lat,lon],radius=10,popup=popup,color=color))

for fg in ddfg.values():
    mymap.add_child(fg)

mymap.add_child(folium.LayerControl())
```

Comment: I guess you could do something like this `mymap = folium.Map()` May I ask why you want to "clear" it?

Comment: I should have thought of that :). Thanks! I'm using it with Jupyter and I want to be able to erase the map to try new things.